# Sequence passed as a varargs argument

Tags: scala

I have an interface

```
object Leaf {
  def apply(keys: Int*): Leaf = {
    new Leaf(keys)
  }
}
```

where Leaf class is defined as follows:

```
class Leaf(keys: Seq[Int]) extends Node(true, keys, Seq())
```

Is this possible to pass a Sequence as a keys parameter? Of course I could create second varargs method, but i wonder if there is a method which converts a Sequence into varargs paremeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and I think you mean varargs not varchar :)

```
Leaf(sequence: _*)
```

Comment: yes varargs its late :) i make question update